# How to stream a mp4 video over stdin/stdout?

Tags: linux, video, streaming, stdin

I need to stream a video to stdout and then read that stream from stdin again to display it. At the end there will be an application in the middle to handle the networking but for now I want to test it directly. When trying this the video timer works however the screen stays black.

```
vlc -I dummy video.mp4 --sout '#standard{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=-}' | vlc -
```

I have also tried gstreamer however I was not able to successfully stream a video yet.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.mp4 ! fdsink | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had to struggle quite a bit with VLC options to make this work, not even sure there are not extra / useless / wrong settings there (like the extra verbosity ;-)
For the record, I got help from [VLC's wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/).

On the receiving side :

```
vlc rtp://192.168.56.101
```

On the sending side :

```
vlc -vvv video.mp4 --sout '#duplicate{dst=display,dst="transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=192.168.56.101,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}"}'
```

NB :

- You'll see 2 videos outputs, which is due to the "duplicate" parameter in the streaming option (values of `--sout`)
- Don't forget to add your workstation's IP address in both commands

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I was looking for a solution which pipes the stream over stdin/stdout so that I can take care of the network transmission myself.